# React Native android adbExe does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, adb

While  i  run  **react  native  android** app in  **visual  code**  i get  this  error. I need  help  to  resolve this  issue.  Thanks.

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:installDebug'.

> File 'C:\Users\Supun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 34s
26 actionable tasks: 26 executed
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old topic, but I'll post it here in case if anyone is having the same issue.

For me, this usually happens when [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) is being used, while Android SDK is installed under Windows (there you have `adb.exe` instead of `adb`).

Making another copy of `adb.exe` binary as `adb` resolved the issue for me:

```
copy adb.exe adb
```

Comment: Awesome! You saved hours of troubleshooting for me. It really works

Comment: Thank you so much !!! That works ! F*****g windows/ubuntu mix that never work ...