# Specified for property 'adb Exe' does not exist (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to build a react-native project but every time shows the following error, But I have installed the adb.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:installDebug'.
> File '/home/praneeth/Android/platform-tools/adb' specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.
```

I reinstalled the adb but no chance to solve the issue.

My build environment is Ubuntu 20.04

**Edit**
Please note that I made another copy of adb binary as adb.exe in other way rounds according to this answer [React Native android adbExe does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007406/react-native-android-adbexe-does-not-exist)

Comment: Possible duplicate, please refer below solution [React Native android adbExe does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007406/react-native-android-adbexe-does-not-exist)

Comment: @SudarakaSenevirathne Before posting this I  referred it. But not luck. The builder worked without error until now. I am wondering This is happened by chance.

Answer (score 0):

According to @dudeperryfect

> I found an answer that said to replace ‘/’ with ‘’ in my settings.gradle in my react native project. The only thing in that is file however is: rootProject.name = ‘AwesomeProject’ include ‘:app’
>
> I have added:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

[React native Android emulator error on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539988/react-native-android-emulator-error-on-ubuntu-18-04)